# Saving arabic tweets from tweepy in CVS

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to retrieve a user's timeline tweets using tweepy (Python 3.6). Now, I found a code with which I can do that and save them in CVS form. It works without problems when retrieving English tweets, yet tweets written in arabic are displayed this way: "b'\xd9\x82\xd8\xaa\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\x...". I've gone through multiple forums and saw this issue being raised several times but I haven't been able to find a solution. I figured it must have something to do with the encoding utf-8, but I do not know how to manipulate the code. Anyone has a suggestion? THANKS!

this is my code:

```
>>> import tweepy
>>> import csv
>>> consumer_key = "..."
>>> consumer_secret = "..."
>>> access_key = "..."
>>> access_secret = "..."
>>> def get_all_tweets(screen_name):

#authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
alltweets = []  

#make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)

#save most recent tweets
alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

#save the id of the oldest tweet less one
oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

#keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
while len(new_tweets) > 0:
    print("getting tweets before %s" % (oldest))

    #all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)

    #save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    #update the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    print("...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets)))

#transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv 
outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in alltweets]

#write the csv  
with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text"])
    writer.writerows(outtweets)

pass

>>> if __name__ == '__main__':
#pass in the username of the account you want to download
get_all_tweets("#username")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.x, there's no need to call `encode()` when writing writing to files as the system `open()` command now defaults to text mode (In Python 2.x, you can use `io.open()`)

Change `tweet.text.encode("utf-8")` to `tweet.text`.

As Python 3 uses your locale to work out what file encoding to use when you open a file in text mode, it's safer to change your `open()` code to:

```
with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

Now, Python will automatically encode any strings to UTF-8 as it writes the file.

Comment: Hi! thanks a lot for this clarification. Unfortunately, now when I open the CSV file the arabic characters appear as: Ø¨Ø³ Ø¨Ø¹Ø¯Ù†ÙŠ Ø¨ØªÙ…Ù†Ù‰ Ø´ÙˆÙ.

Comment: What are you using to open the CSV?

Comment: Oh wait. Good question! I was using Excel, but just realised it works well with TextEdit! Amazing, thank you! Do you by any chance know why this happens with Excel and how it can be overcome?

Comment: Yes, Excel assumes CSVs are encoded in an 8-bit codepage. To force it to read the CSV as UTF-8, change `encoding='utf-8'` to `encoding='utf-8-sig'` and rewrite the CSV file. This will write a UTF-8 BOM at the start of the file.